# What is the use case of unary plus method on Numerical?

Tags: ruby, unary-operator

Given that there is unary `Numerical#-@`, from symmetry, it might be tempting to have `Numerical#+@`, but my understanding is that the design philosophy of Ruby by Matz is that a feature would not be added just for symmetry, but has to have a practical use case.

If the unary `Numerical#+@` were left for user to define freely, that might have been useful. But I cannot think of any use case of it as is pre-defined in Ruby. When would you want to use it?

Comment: Are you asking why the language allows you to write `+42` instead of simply `42` or why is there a method for it? Also *"the design philosophy of Ruby by Matz is that a feature would not be added just for symmetry"* - [Citation needed].

Comment: @ndn What is the difference between them? As for the citation, he repeats it everywhere on the issue tracker in response to some feature request.

Comment: One assumes that `+42` should be invalid syntax, the other that the implementation just shouldn't be available via the public API.

Comment: @ndn As I wrote, I think it would be useful to allow the form `+42` to be syntactic, but its meaning being defined by some user (so that `+42` should raise an undefined method error out of the box).

Comment: I can't think of a single widely used language in which `+42` doesn't equal `42` and instead gives you an error.

Comment: Btw just the other day I stumbled upon [this](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/3131), to suggest it's against the philosophy is strange.